# std::initializer_list as std::array constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, initializer-list

I need to pass arguments to a wrapper class that looks as minimal example like this:

```
template<class TStack, unsigned int TBins>
class Wrapper : Stack<......>
{
    std::array<TStack, TBins> m_oStacks;

    template<typename ... Args>
    Wrapper(std::initializer_list<const unsigned int> const& size, Args&&... args)
    : Stack<.......>(args), m_oStacks{5,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
    //, m_oStacks(size) //,m_oStacks{size} //,m_oStacks{{size}}
    {
        //m_oStacks = { size };           
    }
};
```

I tried to init the array with the initializer_list size but nothing works (commented parts of the source) only the constant {5,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} part does

Someone know the reason and a fix?

Sincerely
Matyro

Edit 1: The main problem is that TStack does (in most cases) not have a default constructor so i need to initialize the array at construction

Comment: @Matyro  Class std::array does not have a constructor that accepts the initializer_list. You should copy initializer_list in the array yourself.

Comment: Use `std::array<TStack, TBins>` instead of `std::initializer_list<const unsigned int>`, it can be list-initialized as well, and a `std::array` itself does have a copy constructor

Comment: That solution works fine, thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `std::initializer_list`:

```
template <typename TStack, std::size_t TBins>
class Wrapper
{
public:
    Wrapper(std::initializer_list<unsigned int> il)
        : Wrapper(il, std::make_index_sequence<TBins>{})
    {
    }

private:
    template <std::size_t... Is>
    Wrapper(std::initializer_list<unsigned int> il, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
        : m_oStacks{{ *(il.begin() + Is)... }}
    {
    }

    std::array<TStack, TBins> m_oStacks;
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a314c01638746311)

With `std::array`:

```
template <typename TStack, std::size_t TBins>
class Wrapper
{
public:
    Wrapper(const std::array<unsigned int, TBins>& a)
        : Wrapper(a, std::make_index_sequence<TBins>{})
    {
    }

private:
    template <std::size_t... Is>
    Wrapper(const std::array<unsigned int, TBins>& a, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
        : m_oStacks{{ a[Is]... }}
    {
    }

    std::array<TStack, TBins> m_oStacks;
};
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bcbc8f5ff783263f)

Comment: I din't think that through all the way.  Looks great.

Comment: The first case results in UB if the length of `il` is smaller than TBINS.