# Forward dynamic number of parameter to constructor

Tags: c++, wrapper, c++14, variadic-templates

This is a follow up question to:
[std::initializer_list as std::array constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35488730/stdinitializer-list-as-stdarray-constructor)

I learned quit a bit from the answer i got there and tried to expand my wrapper class a bit. Here in short words the problem, my Solution and the problems with it.

**Problem**:
I need a class that creates an array from a template without default constructor and an unknown number of arguments. It can itselfed be wrapped from other classes with variadic templates.

**My Solution**: Works but is not really userfriendly therefore i hope for some ideas to improve it
[**Running example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4accc87d13d26441)

```
class a   // some sort of storage class that need wrapper for more functions
{
public:     
   a(int c)
    {
        std::cout << "Class A: " << c << std::endl;
    }
};

template<class TStack>
class b : public TStack  // wrapper with char input
{
public:
    template<class ... TArgs>
    b(char c, TArgs&& ... args)
        : TStack( std::forward<TArgs>(args)...)
    {
        std::cout << "Class B: " << c << std::endl;
    }
};

template<class TStack, unsigned int TBin>
class c  // array wrapper
{
private:

    template<class TStack>
    class d : public TStack   // tuple Expansion
    {
    private:

        template <class ... TArgs, std::size_t... Is>
        d(std::tuple<TArgs...> args, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
            : TStack(std::get<Is>(args)...)
        {}

    public:
        template<class ... TArgs>
        d(std::tuple<TArgs...> args)
            : d(args, std::make_index_sequence< sizeof...(TArgs) >{})
        {}
    };

    std::array< d<TStack>, TBin> data;

    template <class TArgs, std::size_t... Is>
    c(std::initializer_list< TArgs > il, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
        : data{ { *(il.begin() + Is)... } }
    {
    }

public: 
    template<class TArgs>
    c(std::initializer_list< TArgs > il)
       : c(il, std::make_index_sequence<TBin>{})
    {}
};

int main()
{

    a(1);
    b<a>('a', 3);

    c<a, 3>({ std::make_tuple(4), std::make_tuple(5), std::make_tuple(6)});  
    b< c<a, 4> >('a', std::initializer_list<std::tuple<int>>{std::make_tuple(7), std::make_tuple(8), std::make_tuple(9), std::make_tuple(10)}); 

    c< b<a>, 4>({ std::make_tuple('A', 11), std::make_tuple('B', 12), std::make_tuple('C', 13), std::make_tuple('D', 14) });
    b< c< b<a>, 4>>('z', std::initializer_list<std::tuple<char, int>>{ std::make_tuple('A', 11), std::make_tuple('B', 12), std::make_tuple('C', 13), std::make_tuple('D', 14) });
}
```

Why **i dont like my solution**:
The Code works fine, but the `std::initializer_list<std::tuple</*lot of types*/>>` infront of every list is not the most user friendly way i hope for. `make_tuple` is ok but reduces the readability for big lists quite a bit.

Sincerely 
Matyro

Comment: Don't use a braced initializer list, use [a variadic constructor](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aeb49077db6a041b) instead

Comment: Thx, that easier then expected. (Shows me that i still dont understand variadic templates very well. OT: Any good books around to learn more about it?  )